# Using VBA code to Copy Specific value from a cell when the dropdown box changes that value

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and have only recently been developing my excel skills.

I have created 3 different scenarios for an investment project situation, these scenarios appear in cell "h13" as a drop down box with three options being available, best case/worst case/base case.

When you select each scenario the various outputs will change on the sheet and I have set up the following code to change the outputs and display the relevant ones according to the scenario:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$H$13" Then
    ActiveSheet.Scenarios(Target.Value).Show
  End If
```

Now, what I want to achieve is the following:

In Cell E13 I have a numeric value that is my main concern (I should note this is an NPV Formula). Every
   time we change scenario this value obviously changes. 
I would like
   to create a summary table that is simply something like this:
   Scenario 1 = x Scenario 2 = y Scenario 3 = z So Ideally what I want
   to do is, when we select scenario 1 we copy the value from E13 to say
   B21. When we select the next scenario E13 will obviously change,
   however I would like the copied value of B21 to remain the same, and
   now the new Scenario 2 value to be displayed in B22.

I have no real idea how to go about this? I have tried adding this on the bottom but the values do not remain 'static'

```
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("h13")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E13").Copy
    Range("B21:B23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
  End Sub
```

Now I think I know that I need to create a reference so that it would read something like when e13=y then copy, next e13=x copy and loop? it until all outcomes have occured. Not sure how to do it though.

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried to read up on this as much as possible but I cannot really exactly pin point what I need in code terms as I am very new to this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This solution shows the results in a *"range\table"* located at `B20:D23` *(see pictures below)*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rTbl As Range, lRow As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False                        'To avoid triggering again when table is updated

    If Target.Address = "$H$13" Then

        Rem Filters value in target range
        Select Case Target.Value2
        Case "Base case", "Best case", "Worst case"         'Change as required
        Case Else:  GoTo ExitTkn                            'Value is not in the list then exit
        End Select

        Rem Show Scenario
        ActiveSheet.Scenarios(Target.Value).Show

        Rem Update Results
        Set rTbl = Range("B21").Resize(3, 3)                'Change as required
        With rTbl
            lRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, .Columns(1), 0)
            .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Range("E13").Value2     'Updates result - Change as required
            .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Range("D13").Value2     'Updates scenario variable - Change as required
        End With

  End If

ExitTkn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx),
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx)

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for this, the logical process of the code makes sense however I get the following error:
Run-time error 1004
Unable to get the match property of the WorksheetFunction Class

lRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, .Columns(1), False)

Now, I figure that Columns(1) is the issue, but not exactly sure why?

Comment: That error tells you that there is not match, (i.e. `Target.Value` was not found in `Column 1 of the table` not column 1 of the worksheet). You have to ensure that the values in the 1st column of the table are exactly the same as the values in the `DataValidation`.

Comment: Also check that this line has been updated according to the location of the table: `Set rTbl = Range("B21").Resize(3, 3)`. Note that `"B21"` refers to the first row of the table not the header.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out soon after posting, thanks for the help it worked a treat and taught me a bit. Cheers